# Permutation on $1,\dots,n$. Expected value of the number of people with a blocked sight.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, expectation

Let $n\ge10$. $n$ people numbered $1$ to $n$ are standing in line, while the height of person $i$ is $i$. We'd say that the sight of person $i$ is blocked if there exists a $j$ such that $j>i$ which stands in front of it in line. Let $X$ be the number of persons that their sight is blocked.

> What is the expected value and variance of X?

I'd appreciate any hint or direction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_i$ be a random variable which is $1$ if person $i$ has their sight blocked, for $1\le i \le n$. Notice that
$$
X=X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n.
$$
Using linearity of expectation, $EX=EX_1+EX_2+\dots+EX_n$, and each $EX_i$ is just the probability that person $i$'s sight is blocked.

For the variance, 
$$
\text{Var }X = \sum_i \text{Var }X_i + \sum_{i\neq j}\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j)
$$
The first summation ranges from $i=1$ to $n$, while the second is over all ordered pairs $(i,j)$ with both $i,j$ in $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ for which $i\neq j$. Be careful to include both $(i,j)$ and $(j,i)$!

Letting $E_i$ be the event that $i$'s vision is blocked, its not too hard to show $\text{Var }X_i=P(E_i)(1-P(E_i))$, while $\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j) = P(E_i\cap E_j)-P(E_i)P(E_j)$. Once you compute these probabilities, you have your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have been able to compute $\mathbb{P}(E_i)=1-\frac{1}{n-i+1}$. However, how can I calculate $\mathbb{P}(E_i\cap E_j)$? They are not independent.

Comment: This is where the tricky combinatorics comes in. You need to count the number of permutations where both persons $i$ and $j$ are shorter than someone ahead of them. Instead, count the complement; permutations where either $i$ is taller then those in front, or $j$ is. Principle of inclusion-exclusion is useful here.

Comment: This problem would have been much cleaner if it instead asked about $Y$, the number of people whose vision was _not_ blocked. Writing $Y=\sum_i Y_i$ as before, the $P(Y_i=1)=1/(n-i+1)$, while $P(Y_i=1\cap Y_j=1)$ is much nicer to compute. Note $Y=n-X$, so Var $X=$ Var $Y$.

Comment: I don't really understand how to use inclusion-exculsion here.